# Difference between df.plot(kind='bar') and df.plot.bar()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I use Python 3.12.1 and pandas 2.2.0.
I find `df.plot(kind='bar')` and `df.plot.bar()` work in a similar (or even the same?) way.

1. Is there any difference between these two?
2. Which is the preferred way?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are so close to the final answer. As you mentioned in your code, According to the documentation, what these methods return is `matplotlib.axes.Axes` or `numpy.ndarray`.

Here is what `df.plot(kind='bar')` returns :

[image]

And here is what `df.plot.bar()` returns :

[image]

So the output is equivalent when you are using them with default argument values, Unless you change the `backend` in `df.plot()`.

Answer (score 1):

Therefore, you can use either of them depending on your preference. If you want to create a simple bar plot, df.plot.bar() is a good choice. If you want to create a more complex plot, df.plot(kind='bar') is more flexible and can be used to create other types of plots as well.